# Javascript when live time strikes 23:00

Tags: javascript, if-statement, time

I have be attempting this for quite a while now and cant get my head around it. I have a javascript which displays a live time. What i am trying to do is build an if statement that says if it hits 23:00:00 then open a link. can anyone help please? anything i use just blanks out the time :(

```
<script>
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};
    return i;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="startTime()">

<div id="txt"></div>
```

Comment: seems like it is a basic if statement. What did you try that did not work?

Comment: I thought it may have been. Im very new to javascript so i have been trying to convert to php and do an if statement from there.

Comment: yeah, why does `if(h >= 23) openLink()` or similar not work?

Comment: PHP runs on the server, not sure how it would work with JavaScript....

Comment: I understand the principle behind an if but i am not sure what i would be looking up in the if. if i do the get element or use i or text it just returns blank and removes the timer

Comment: @epascarello makes a good point, that you can't get a "live time" using php....

Comment: can you paste some broken code in the question so we have a better idea of what might be wrong?

Comment: @jRogers than sounds like you had an error and the code did not run. Show what you tried. Could be a simple syntax issue.

Answer (score 1):

You already calculate the time, just check to see if it's the time you want, and [open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) a url.

```js
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date('Thu Jul 26 2018 23:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)')

  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  if (h === 23 && m === 0 && s === 0) {
    window.open('https://www.stackoverflow.com', '_blank');
  }
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
  };
  return i;
}
```

```html
<body onload="startTime()">

  <div id="txt"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Be careful with `===`. The `checkTime` function returns a string with a leading zero if the number is less than 10.

Comment: Coincidental timing! I actually meant to put it before the string conversions. Might as well work on the un-formatted data.

Answer (score 1):

A simple

```
...
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

if (h == "23" && m == "00" && s == "00") {
  alert("open link from here");
}
...
```

would do the trick.

**Note:**
You also have to check for `s` otherwise you'll open a new page every second.

Answer (score 1):

**refresh every second :**

```
function timeLoop(){

  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  var timeString = h+":"+m+":"+s
  // print time
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  // check timeString
  if ( timeString === "23:00:00"){
    // perform you actions here
  }
}

document.body.onload = function(){
  setInterval( timeLoop, 1000 );
}
```

**What's happening here is**

when body is loaded the `timeLoop` function starts looping every second, each loop updates the time displayed and checking it.

you can execute whatever code or function in side the if statement.

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly. It also helped give me a better understanding

Comment: you're welcome, and please respond here if you had any other issues but remember to show your efforts also.
Accept this as an answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple `setInterval()` checking for the hour only would do it. The following code sets a  interval checking the hour every 1 second. If the hour is 23 the interval is cleared to ensure that the triggered action runs only once and then does whatever you want to do. There is no need to check for minutes and seconds as well and this way you don't need to worry about leading zeros.

```js
var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
  var h = new Date().getHours();
  if (h === 23) {
    // clear interval to ensure that code runs only once
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    // do whatever you like
    console.log(h);
  }
},1000);
```